# Mapping Json String to Multiple Objects

Tags: c#, json, mapping, deserialization

Rewriting the question for conciseness.

I need to be able to deserialize and/or map a json string to multiple concrete objects at once, some of which are nested. I have no control over the json string I'm receiving. How would I go about doing this?

Example:

```
// Example objects
public class ClassA
{
    public string Prop1 { get; set; }
    public string Prop2 { get; set; }
    public string Prop3 { get; set; }
}

public class ClassB
{
    public string Prop1 { get; set; }
    public string Prop2 { get; set; }
    public string Prop3 { get; set; }
    public ClassC Nested { get; set; }
}

public class ClassC
{
    public string Prop1 { get; set; }
    public string Prop2 { get; set; }
    public string Prop3 { get; set; }
}

//Example "records" or rows

// All values
{
    "ClassA.Prop1" : "Value"
    "ClassA.Prop2" : "Value"
    "ClassA.Prop3" : "Value"
    "ClassB.Prop1" : "Value"
    "ClassB.Prop2" : "Value"
    "ClassB.Prop3" : "Value"
    "ClassB.Nested.Prop1" : "Value"
    "ClassB.Nested.Prop2" : "Value"
    "ClassB.Nested.Prop3" : "Value"
}

// Partial Data
{
    "ClassA.Prop1" : "Value"
    "ClassA.Prop2" : "Value"
    "ClassB.Prop1" : "Value"
    "ClassB.Nested.Prop1" : "Value"
    "ClassB.Nested.Prop2" : "Value"
}
```

Comment: Just a thought, you could look at querying your spreadsheet using ADO.NET instead of Excel Interop (depending on whether you need the exposed Excel functionality).  You then would not worry about mapping - access the columns by their column name if all you need is to import the data.  You do need to have the appropriate Access drivers installed, however. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/lazydeveloper/2010/03/15/using-ado-net-to-work-with-excel-files/

Comment: I probably focused too much on the Excel. Pulling it out of Excel isn't an issue. It's more just taking the KVP's (column name, value) and mapping it to objects and nested objects.

Comment: What d you mean mapping it to objects and nested objects? Can you provide an example?

Comment: An example might help.  I'm not sure what *"I need to map items in each record to concrete objects, some of which will be nested objects"* means

Comment: I rewrote the question to be more concise, and to maybe help future readers. I have since figured out my own solution. It's provided below. If anyone knows of or comes up with something better, I'd love to know about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies for the lack of conciseness in the question. I'd been struggling with this one for days and was beating my head against the keyboard, and threw this question up without clearly thinking about the problem.

I just solved my own problem. The issue was that I was trying to go straight from an unnormalized data set serialized in json to concrete objects, which is messy. Whether or not they were nested was irrelevant. The answer was that I was looking at the model the entire time. I needed to deserialize into an object that represented a row (or record) in the spreadsheet. From there, it's really easy to extract the concrete objects and setup the relationships that are needed. The short answer? I was trying to skip a step. Here's the solution.

```
public class SpreadsheetRow
{
    public string ClassAProp1 { get; set; }
    public string ClassAProp2 { get; set; }
    public string ClassAProp3 { get; set; }
    public string ClassBProp1 { get; set; }
    public string ClassBProp2 { get; set; }
    public string ClassBProp3 { get; set; }
    public string ClassCProp1 { get; set; }
    public string ClassCProp2 { get; set; }
    public string ClassCProp3 { get; set; }

    public ClassA GetClassA()
    {
        return new ClassA
        {
            Prop1 = ClassAProp1,
            Prop2 = ClassAProp2,
            Prop3 = ClassAProp3,
        };
    }

    public ClassB GetClassB()
    {
        return new ClassB
        {
            Prop1 = ClassBProp1,
            Prop2 = ClassBProp2,
            Prop3 = ClassBProp3,
            Nested = new ClassC
            {
                Prop1 = ClassCProp1,
                Prop2 = ClassCProp2,
                Prop3 = ClassCProp3,
            }
        };
    }
}
}
```